# Publish project of the asp.net MVC issue - Create database permission denied

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have published my project in Asp.Net MVC in the local server but there was some error in the database. Below is that error message:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

My connection string is as below.

```
connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-LBLR0NH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=False; User Id=zahra; password=12345" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So what is the problems and how I can fixed this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message appears when the user that is trying to create the database doesn't have the necessary permissions in SQL Server.

Open the Security folder, then open the Logins folder and select the user account under which you want to create the database.

Open the account's Properties, select the Server Roles tab and then select the dbcreator checkbox (sysadmin works even better).

Please have a look into this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78388/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-unable-to-get-the-permis).

Comment: Add member failed for ServerRole 'dbcreator'.  when i try to do the role this message error come

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper First of thing you need to login with the user which has already this access role of debcreator then you need to select the required database and set permission of dbcreator to that database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the zahra sql login exits, and has at least dbcreator server role to create databases.